# IP Fragmentation confusing

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, ip-fragmentation

Basically I'm new to networking and I was trying work  an example on fragmentation. Here is the question

**Illustrate fragmentation in the form of a table given the following detail: Size of data = 24000 bits, offset =
370, M=1, D = 0 and the New MTU is 1500 bytes.**

Here is my answer, DF= Do not fragment and MF = More Fragment, 24000 bits = 3000 bytes.

```html
Id | Data Length| Data| DF | MF| Offset|
________________________________________
x  | 1500       | 1480| 0  | 1 | 370   |
----------------------------------------
x  | 1500       | 1480| 0  | 1 | 577   |
----------------------------------------
x  |   40       |   20| 1  | 0 | 744   |
________________________________________
```

I was wondering if this answer was good precisely for the offset column. Can Someone help?

Comment: Given what question? There is no apparent question here.

Comment: Hi @EJP sorry for the inconvenient :) I have updated the question. So basically I have the task to fragment the data from the info given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems good, so here is the solution

1. If total Data equals to 2980, answer is good.
2. If you are dividing  the data by 8 and then increment by this factor, answer is good.